# "Build path entry is missing" error when trying to create a new project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

> Build path entry is missing:
>    org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7

I get this error when I create a new project in Eclipse. I am using Ubuntu by the way.

Can anyone help me fixing this?

Comment: Did you remove a JDK from your computer ?

Comment: No I didn't remove anything. I installed JDK 1.7.

Comment: Check that update-java-alternatives are set to the right jdk

Comment: I tried to set it to Oracles JDK but it didnt work. Gave me an error so I set it back to OpenJDK.

Comment: Ok I fixed the issue myself :) Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: @IlhamiD When you solve yourself a question, it's a good practice to write the solution as an answer so that it may help somebody else later. You may also accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is an old question, but I solved it by modifying JRE system library and select a valid Execution environment in my case (Mac OSX) JRE 1.6

Comment: how you did this, can you wrote step by step?

Comment: @Line properties->java build path ->libraries-> add library ->jre system library -> in my case i added jre 8.x and removed existing old jre after then my src(java,test) folders added without any error. good luck..

Answer (score 35):

This error is due to JRE System Library. Maybe you didn't give appropriate JRE for eclipse project to run. SO follow below steps.

1. Right-click on the project and choose properties.
2. Click on the Java Build Path option in the left side menu.
3. From the Java Build Path window, click on the Libraries Tab.
4. Make sure JRE System library is listed, if it is not listed then you can add, by clicking "Add Library" from the right side menu.
5. So if JRE System Library is already listed then  **double click** on JRE System Library which was showing error on **Java Build Path** window **Libraries** tab previously .
6. Then it will open another window called **JRE System Library** . So in that window choose **Alternate JRE** . From that drop down choose your JRE.

In my case, it is java-8-openjdk-amd64 , as I am using ubuntu 16.04. Like that you can also choose your JRE System library .

Answer (score 1):

This is because JRE is not present in the build path of your project. So trying adding JRE from Windows->Preferences->Installed JREs and Add the default JRE. After that the JRE gets added by default in the build path of every project. This should solve the issue

Comment: Which is "default"? I have "Execution Environment Description", "Standard 1.1.x VM" and "Standard VM". Did you mean the third?

Comment: Add it from from Standard VM

Answer (score 0):

I already had JDK installed but i still had errors, so I opened command prompt locating it to my project:  `c:\project\proj>`. Then I ran `mvn clean && mvn install`.
That solved my issue !

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by configure the .classpath file. I use maven and I deleted a line with some invalid setting in the marked place shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>

    -----some files which is actually deleted in my project, I delete this line and all works fine------

    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Copy any past two file (.classpath and .project) from an existing java project which is running properly, it is present inside your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new project on Eclipse (file -> others -> java -> Java Project), on the "Create Java Project", after you typed your project's name, scroll down a bit and "tick" the [create module-info java file].

Click next. It'll ask you for your module's name. You can give whatever you want.

Then on the right side "project explorer", in the src package, create a class. It'll show errors. At that time, just delete your "module-info.java" file which should be inside the same [src] file.

Now you can run your project. At least that's how I got it worked.

[Edit] - Alternatively, if you create a new package inside the "src" package and then you create your classes in that newly created project, you necessarily don't have to delete "module-info.java".