# Error during creating a new project in Java EE Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a very inexperienced programmer and I don`t have any idea what I should do. I am using Windows 10.
Eclipse shows me this:
 Build path entry is missing: org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/OSGi%Minimum-1.2

I know that it is something with JRE System Library but I couldn`t solve this problem alone.
Can anyone help me fixing this?

Comment: Maybe this topic can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252123/build-path-entry-is-missing-error-when-trying-to-create-a-new-project-in-eclip

Comment: Thanks, but I have seen this topic before but it still doesn`t work.

Comment: Right click on the JRE System Library mode in the Package Explorer. Are you able to configure or modify it into one that works?

Answer (score 0):

I installed Eclipse again and everything is ok now. Problem solved ;)